How to introspect a protoc plugin? (Or fix the gen-bq-schema plugin)
I think the entire problem is hard to answer without further investigation. So first I simply want to know how to introspect the problem.
Problem Overview
I use the protoc-gen-bq-schema plugin to assist with converting some large and complex protocol buffer messages into BigQuery schemas.
Until recently, I had an Ubuntu machine.  I now have an M3 Mac, the Apple ARM64 chip. I can no longer get the plugin to work, but I can't manage to introspect the problem:  no errors, no messages, nothing. I'm not too savvy with how to use plugins with protoc
I carried over my command history from the previous machine, so I know I used to do exactly the same command that I've been trying now. It was fairly simple:
protoc --bq-schema_out . -I <the/path/to/the/proto/package> <the/path/to/the/proto/file/to/generate/the/schema>

After installing protoc, Go, and the protoc-gen-bq-schema plugin on my new computer, I tried that same command, and it returns with absolutely nothing, no input, no errors... nothing.

I tried something available by default with protoc and it works perfectly:
protoc --python_out . -I <the/path/to/the/proto/package> <the/path/to/the/proto/file/to/generate/the/schema>

This generates the protobuf as a Python module, fully functional. So it seems clear that the problem is with the plugin (or with how protoc interacts with the plugin).

I then tried to introspect, to see if I could understand what is going wrong, but I don't really understand what I can do or how to do it.  I tried the following:
> protoc-gen-bq-schema --help

Usage of protoc-gen-bq-schema:
  -alsologtostderr
        log to standard error as well as files
  -log_backtrace_at value
        when logging hits line file:N, emit a stack trace
  -log_dir string
        If non-empty, write log files in this directory
  -logtostderr
        log to standard error instead of files
  -stderrthreshold value
        logs at or above this threshold go to stderr
  -v value
        log level for V logs
  -vmodule value
        comma-separated list of pattern=N settings for file-filtered logging

So I tried to pass some type of logging:
protoc --bq-schema_out .  --bq-schema_opt=-logtostderr <path/to/proto/file/to/generate/schema> -I <path/to/proto/package>

I wasn't sure if I write --bq-schema_opt=-logtostderr or --bq-schema_opt=logtostderr or --bq-schema_opt=--logtostderr.  I tried them all, none worked.  I also tried passing the v (verbose) flag, nothing.
It seems as if, even though the protoc-gen-bq-schema file is installed properly and can be called on its own, it isn't being seen at all by protoc. Or, it could be that the protoc-gen-bq-schema plugin is not working correctly, but it can at least generate its help message.
Request
I don't think it is possible to understand what is wrong with the plugin itself, but if you could help me understand how I can introspect protoc, that would be great. I cannot get any output regarding what it is doing, so I cannot even begin to guess what I need to do to fix the problem.

Hi @mike, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP support case  . Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the  issue tracker  describing your issue.

Thanks, @SouravDutta.  So, does this mean that the plugin is now officially supported by Google / GCP?  I was under the impression it was not.

@SouravDutta , I tried to follow your guidance:  we don't have the contract level to allow for support cases, and the issue tracker does not allow for me to submit it in "Miscellaneous", which is the closest to the correct location. :(  I don't understand why GCP does not just enable the "Issues" tab in the GitHub repo like everyone else does.

HI Mike, from here you can create the PIT public issue tracker   . just sign in and create . While creating elaborate the issue deeply in the issue description portion .

Have you tried running with arch -x86_64 <your_command>. Got me out of trouble at times with M1.

arch ... did not help, but thanks for the suggestion.  As I mentioned in the question, it also stopped working for my old Linux machine, so I didn't expect it to be machine-specific.
